# whenever gem command not running on intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

on the whenever gem I am getting everything right . and can udpate the schedule.rb file but not getting logs after every time interval . Here is the code

this is schedule file

```
every 2.minutes do
 command "echo 'you can use raw cron sytax too'"
 rake "ftp" 
end
```

This is ftp.rake file in lib/tasks/

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'timeout'
require 'pathname'
require 'fileutils'
task :ftp do
    command "echo 'you can use raw cron sytax too'"
    ftp = nil
    f = File.open("/home/hb/demo_haml/log/ftp_transfer.log","w+")    
    f.write("\n#{Time.now}")
    ftp = Net::FTP::new("192.168.x.x")
    ftp.login("demo", "demo")
    ftp.chdir("/home/hd")
    ftp.getbinaryfile("one.conf", "/home/hb/demo_haml/conf/one.conf", 1024)
    ftp.close if ftp
    f.close
end
```

After this i get the time on the log for the first time when i fire 
 `whenever --update-crontab store`

Running `crontab -l`

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: demo_haml
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'echo '\''you can use raw cron sytax too'\'''

0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/hb/applications/other_old_apps/Arpit/demo_haml && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ftp --silent'
```

What to do to keep on executing after every interval?

Comment: It's the cron that executes these tasks. What's in your crontab after you run the `whenever --update-crontab store` command? You can check it with `crontab -l`. I am assuming you are going through http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby?view=asciicast

Comment: I have updated the question. Pleaes check. And yes i am following the same link for reference